# how to achieved sprite reflection in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am currently working on an open world game like pokemon using libgdx.I am currently stuck on this effect that I really want to be done before moving to other features of my game. do you have any idea how to achieve this reflection effect? .concept behind?

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102940/libgdx-sprite-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic reflection, to draw a texture flipped vertically you can simply scale its height by -1. Then simply redraw the texture an appropriate distance under the player.

You shoudl also add a clipping rectangle around the water's edge so the reflection only draws where the water is. For perfomance purposes, it would also be good to only do this when the player is near water.

I can't give you actual code as I don;t know anything about your code, but once you've had a go at handling reflection as abaove, come back here and ask any more specific questions taht you may have.

This question is too broad and opinion based and hence is highly likely to be voted down.

Comment: Thanks phil. I will try this approach. Hope it won't be down voted

Comment: up. be back soon, after school.